# Displaying rows of data in columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, union

I have a relational database structure relating to football matches, and I am trying to create a view in MySQL that will allow me to display only the fields I want the user to see.

The problem is that the `match_result` table contains double the number of rows as `match_main`, as the number of goals scored is recorded for the home and away club as a separate record in this table.

I want to display the following fields in one view:

• match_id
• status_no
• season
• date_time
• stadium_name
• attendance
• **referee_name** (referee_first_name and referee_last_name concatenated)
• **home_club**
• **home_goal**
• **away_club**
• **away_goal**
• bbc_url
• sky_url

- The field names listed in bold do not actually exist in the database.
- the home_team field in `match_result` is a boolean field to determine if the club played at home (1) or away (0)

My database structure looks like this:

[image]

This is my code thus far. It is returning the maximum number of records (4940), which is the total number of unique matches played:

```sql
 SELECT 
        match_main.match_id AS match_id,
        season.season AS Season,
        CONCAT(referee.referee_first_name,' ',referee.referee_last_name) AS `Referee`,
        match_status.status_no AS Status,
        match_main.attendance AS Attendance,
        match_main.date_time` AS Date,
        match_main.bbc_url` AS 'BBC URL'
        match_main.sky_url` AS 'Sky URL'
    FROM
        match_main
        LEFT JOIN referee ON ((match_main.referee_id = referee.referee_id)))
        LEFT JOIN season ON ((match_main.season_id = season.season_id
        LEFT JOIN match_status ON ((match_main.status_id = match_status.status_id)))
```

This code outputs:

[image]

Comment: Imo, you don't need a `UNION` to make this work. You can create two joins to the `match_result` table, one for the home team and one for the away team. This will allow you to return both teams in a single row, as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you could achieve this by creating two `JOIN`s to the `match_result` table which will allow you to electively join on the home and away club:

```
SELECT 
        match_main.match_id AS match_id,
        season.season AS Season,
        CONCAT(referee.referee_first_name,' ',referee.referee_last_name) AS `Referee`,
        match_status.status_no AS Status,
        match_main.attendance AS Attendance,
        match_main.date_time` AS Date,
        match_main.bbc_url` AS 'BBC URL',
        match_main.sky_url` AS 'Sky URL',
        c1.club_name AS home_club,
        mr1.goal AS home_goal,
        c2.club_name AS away_club,
        mr2.goal AS away_goal
    FROM
        match_main
        LEFT JOIN referee ON ((match_main.referee_id = referee.referee_id)))
        LEFT JOIN season ON ((match_main.season_id = season.season_id
        LEFT JOIN match_status ON ((match_main.status_id = match_status.status_id)))
        LEFT JOIN match_result mr1 ON ((mr1.match_id = match_main.match_id AND mr1.home_team = 1))
        LEFT JOIN club c1 ON ((c1.club_id = mr1.club_id))
        LEFT JOIN match_result mr2 ON ((mr2.match_id = match_main.match_id AND mr2.home_team = 0))
        LEFT JOIN club c2 ON ((c2.club_id = mr2.club_id))
```

In the above *untested* code, there are two separate `JOIN`s to the `match_result` and the `club` tables.  This allows you to return the home and away teams as individual columns in the same row.

This is perfectly valid, and using separate *table aliases* allows you to achieve this.  `mr1` and `c1` are the table aliases for the home team, and `mr2` and `c2` are the aliases for the away team.

The `JOIN` between the `match_main` and `mr1` \ `mr2` tables takes place on the `home_team` column, which allows the selection between home and away team based on your table structure.

Comment: Made it look very easy! Thanks a lot.